# calculate two different date value from textbox by calender and display remaining day without submit button

Tags: javascript

I am using two textboxes fromdate and todate with calender if i enter two different date in that textbox, I wants to display remaining days left in another text box from total leaves.

Comment: when you set the date from the calendar, it must be giving an event. EG: onDateSelection or onDateChanged. onChange might be triggering for the input box. Try to use the events and set the difference value.

Comment: add some code.What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want the difference between the two dates to be calculated? What do you mean by remaining days left?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your code using `Jquery`

```
var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

it will display **time difference** in **hour**

**[have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBNN/113/)**